# Oracle trigger for calculating an attribute inside nested table

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table (Compra) and a nested table inside it (lineasCompra). There is the structure of those tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Linea_Compra_ntabtyp AS TABLE OF Linea_Compra_ObjTyp;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Compra_ObjTyp AS OBJECT (
    num_compra NUMBER(8),
    fecha_compra DATE,
    precio_totalc NUMBER(5,2),
    lineasCompra Linea_Compra_ntabtyp,
    Usuario REF Usuario_ObjTyp,
    Pago lista_Ref_Pago,
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Linea_Compra_ObjTyp AS OBJECT(
    id_lcompra NUMBER(8),
    puc NUMBER(5,2),
    iva NUMBER(3,2),
    pvp NUMBER(5,2),
    Juego REF Juego_ObjTyp,
);
```

The case is, for each row in **LineasCompra** I want the trigger to calculate the ***pvp = puc * (1+iva)***.

For that i got a view *Compras* which is identical to the table Compra. That is what i've tried:

Notes:

- **Act_IVACompra** is for table *Compra*, while **Act_IVACompra_N** is for the nested table.*
- VPT is the precio_total attribute on the Compra table, which is the addition of the **pvp** of all nested tables.
- PT is a temporal variable for the pvp inside the nested table

```
--for the main table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_IvaCompra
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON Compras
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        VPT NUMBER;
        I BINARY_INTEGER;
    BEGIN
        IF :NEW.lineasCompra IS NOT NULL THEN
            VPT := 0;
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.lineasCompra.COUNT LOOP
                VPT := VPT + :NEW.lineasCompra(I).pvp;
            END LOOP;
        ELSE
            VPT := 0;
        END IF;

        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO COMPRA_OBJTAB
            VALUES (:NEW.num_compra, :NEW.fecha_compra, VPT, :NEW.lineasCompra, :NEW.USUARIO, :NEW.PAGO);
        END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE COMPRA_OBJTAB SET num_compra = :NEW.num_compra, fecha_compra = :NEW.fecha_compra, precio_totalc = VPT, lineasCompra = :NEW.lineasCompra, Usuario = :NEW.Usuario, Pago = :NEW.Pago
            WHERE num_compra = :OLD.num_compra;
        END IF;
END;


--for the nested table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_IVACompra_N
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE
    ON NESTED TABLE lineasCompra OF Compras
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    PT NUMBER;
    BEGIN
        PT := :NEW.puc*(1+:NEW.iva);
        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO TABLE (SELECT lineasCompra FROM COMPRA_OBJTAB WHERE num_compra = :PARENT.num_compra)
                VALUES (:NEW.id_lcompra, :NEW.puc, :NEW.iva, PT, :NEW.Juego);
        END IF;

        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE TABLE (SELECT lineasCompra FROM COMPRA_OBJTAB WHERE num_compra = :PARENT.num_compra)
                SET id_lcompra = :NEW.id_lcompra, puc = :NEW.puc, iva = :NEW.iva, pvp = PT, Juego = :NEW.Juego
                WHERE id_lcompra = :NEW.id_lcompra;
        END IF;
    END;
```

The insertion i've tried is:

```
INSERT INTO Compras VALUES (14,'04-03-2021',NULL ,Linea_Compra_nTabTyp(Linea_Compra_ObjTyp(1,13.00,0.21,NULL,
(SELECT REF(J) FROM Juego_ObjTab J WHERE ID=1))), 
(SELECT REF(U) FROM Usuario_ObjTab U WHERE id_usuario=1), 
(SELECT CAST(COLLECT(REF(P)) AS lista_Ref_Pago) FROM Pago_ObjTab P));
```

where the NULL values refer to the precio_total (VPT) and pvp (PT).

The result I get from the insertion is that neither *precio_total* nor *pvp* are calculated (both as NULL).

Probably it could be a stupid issue, but i'm not able to detect where is the problem. Thank you so much.

Added some code after edit

```
CREATE TABLE Compra_ObjTab OF Compra_ObjTyp (
    num_compra PRIMARY KEY,
    fecha_compra NOT NULL,
    CHECK (precio_totalc >= 0)
) NESTED TABLE lineasCompra STORE AS Lineas_Compra_ntab ((PRIMARY KEY(nested_table_id, id_lcompra), 
    CHECK (puc >= 0),
    CHECK (iva >= 0),
    CHECK (pvp > 0)))
  NESTED TABLE Pago STORE AS pagoc_ref_objtab;

ALTER TABLE Lineas_Compra_ntab ADD (SCOPE FOR (Juego) IS Juego_ObjTab);

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Compras AS
    SELECT * FROM Compra_ObjTab;
```

Comment: Please show your ddl for the table Compra and view Compras

Comment: I think I added (at the end of the post) what you asked me for @SayanMalakshinov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your insert pvp is null, so just add NVL():
dbms_output added just to show debug:

```
--for the main table
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Act_IvaCompra
    INSTEAD OF INSERT OR UPDATE ON Compras
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        VPT NUMBER;
        I BINARY_INTEGER;
        lpn Linea_Compra_ObjTyp;
        l_puc NUMBER(5,2);
        l_iva NUMBER(3,2);
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('Act_IvaCompra');
      dbms_output.put_line(:NEW.lineasCompra.COUNT);
        IF :NEW.lineasCompra IS NOT NULL THEN
          dbms_output.put_line('not null');
            VPT := 0;
            FOR I IN 1..:NEW.lineasCompra.COUNT LOOP
                lpn := :NEW.lineasCompra(I);
                dbms_output.put_line('puc:'||lpn.puc);
                dbms_output.put_line('iva:'||lpn.iva);
                dbms_output.put_line('pvp:'||lpn.pvp);
                
                VPT := VPT + nvl(:NEW.lineasCompra(I).pvp, :NEW.lineasCompra(I).puc*(1+:NEW.lineasCompra(I).iva));
              dbms_output.put_line('loop i:'||i||', VPT='||VPT);
            END LOOP;
        ELSE
          dbms_output.put_line('null - VPT = 0');
            VPT := 0;
        END IF;

        IF INSERTING THEN
            INSERT INTO COMPRA_OBJTAB
            VALUES (:NEW.num_compra, :NEW.fecha_compra, VPT, :NEW.lineasCompra, :NEW.USUARIO, :NEW.PAGO);
        END IF;
        IF UPDATING THEN
            UPDATE COMPRA_OBJTAB SET num_compra = :NEW.num_compra, fecha_compra = :NEW.fecha_compra, precio_totalc = VPT, lineasCompra = :NEW.lineasCompra, Usuario = :NEW.Usuario, Pago = :NEW.Pago
            WHERE num_compra = :OLD.num_compra;
        END IF;
END;
/
```